# Angular Material AutoComplete Not Loading Options MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am working on my AutoComplete widget, using Angular JS - Material, in C# ASP.NET MVC.

In this example, I'm trying to get an AutoComplete of States to work. I started with this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_autocomplete.htm), but need to have the options come from the database (at this point, just static list of options in the controller).

Here is a [link](https://github.com/SarahWallis/AutoComplete_AngularMaterial) to my current code (relevant files).

When I run the code, I can see that the list of objects from the controller are pulling through properly - an array of 4 objects, each with an Id and a Name (as shown in my controller method). However, the options are not being loaded into the input form.

When I click into the textbox, I get an "option" that says `No states matching "" were found.` If I type in 'a', I get the "option" that says `No states matching "a" were found.` This is what I would expect to happen if there actually were no matching results.

**My question:** How do I change my code to load the options with what I'm pulling from the controller?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my answer below, answer your question?  Do you need anymore help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix the problem:

1. Changed to POST
2. Set variable = result, then returned the results

Here's the code:

```
function querySearch(query) {
  if (query == undefined) {
    console.log("invalid");
    return;
  }
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: self.URL_Get + query,
    searchTerm: query
  }).then(function(response) {
    self.states = response.data;
  });
  return self.states;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screen shot of the results:

[image: c# angulajs autocomplete angular-material]

Here's the key JavaScript/AngularJS code:

```
//TODO: Replace data.json with /Home/GetStates
$http.get('data.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    self.states = response.data.map(function(state) {
      return {
        value: state.Name.toLowerCase(),
        display: state.Name
      };
    });
  });
```

You'll need to replace `'data.json'` with `'/Home/GetStates'` for it to call your backend MVC JSON RESTful API Service.  Note that I also left the functions `querySearch(query)` and `createFilterFor(query)` in place and changed `self.states=loadStates()` to `self.states=null` since the `$http.get()` service will now load the states.

I did test your C# MVC controller code and everything looks good with it.

Here's a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/tDC6KcO1O8VSGwVghBo7?p=preview.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you need anything else.